# Calculating the Legendre symbol

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, legendre-symbol

Not sure what's going wrong with the calculation here, trying to calculate the Legendre Symbol

$\left(\frac{138}{461}\right)$.

My process follows as $\left(\frac{138}{461}\right) = \left(\frac{2}{461}\right)\left(\frac{3}{461}\right)\left(\frac{23}{461}\right) = \left(\frac{461}{2}\right)\left(\frac{461}{3}\right)\left(\frac{461}{23}\right) = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)\left(\frac{1}{23}\right) = 1*-1 *1 = -1$

But $x^2 \equiv 138\ mod\ 461$ is soluble so something must have went wrong, not sure exactly what.

First I use the fact that if $a \equiv a' (mod\ p)$, then $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{a'}{p}\right)$.

Then I use quadratic reciprocity since $461 \equiv 1\ mod\ 4$. From then on,  I simply evaluate it (ex. 461 mod 2) and get $-1$. But the answer should be $1$ so I'm not sure where I went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the prime 2 separately.

$$   461 \equiv 5 \pmod 8 $$
$$  (2|461) = -1 $$

Comment: Mind elaborating based on the steps I wrote out?

Comment: @SS' there is no Legendre symbol $(a|p)$ when $p=2.$

Comment: Oh yeah, silly mistake. Thanks.